Problema al mapear una API desde javascript
estoy realizando mi tarea de un curso la cual consiste en llamar una API utilizando XMLHttpRequest. El codigo es el siguiente:
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET','http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
xhr.addEventListener('load', function respuesta() {
    if(this.status === 200){
        const data = JSON.parse(this.response)
        const HTMLResponse = document.querySelector("#app")
        const tpl = data.map((user) => '<li>${user.name} ${user.email}</li>)')
        HTMLResponse.innerHTML = '<ul>${tpl}</ul>' 
    }
})
xhr.send()

vscode me dice que la variable tpl esta declarada pero que no obtiene respuesta, al parecer mi programa no estaría tomando las ${} que otra cosa podria probar? o como hago para que me devuelva en mi página esos datos que le solicito a la API?


El string template (template literals) es con backticks `
el resultado del map es un array así que conviene hacerle un .join('') para que quede como string ( sino aparecen unas , separando los elementos )



const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET','http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
xhr.addEventListener('load', function respuesta() {
    if(this.status === 200){
        const data = JSON.parse(this.response)
        const HTMLResponse = document.querySelector("#app")
        const tpl = data.map((user) => `<li>${user.name} ${user.email}</li>`)
        HTMLResponse.innerHTML = `<ul>${tpl.join('')}</ul>` 
    }
})
xhr.send()
<div id=app></div>




Gracias! funciona a la perfección!
